# Using R in the interactive shell with prewritten code

Tags: r, shell

Rather than trying to use:

```
R < filename.r --vanilla
```

You can load prewritten code with

```
source ('filename.R')
```

This can also be added to an .RProfile file if it needs to be loaded each time.

Comment: Use `Rscript filename.r` or `R CMD BATCH filename.r`. You can have some details on `Rscript` by execuiting `Rscript --help`.

Comment: @nicola I am not struggling with the execution, I want to keep the interactivity of R in terminal, just want to load a few lines of preamble (like adding the correct libraries and defining constants) rather than retyping it each time and then continue as you do when you just open the R interpreter.

Comment: If that is your problem, you can write a `.Rprofile` file in your directory and it will be executed at the start of your R session. See for example http://www.statmethods.net/interface/customizing.html